# Pyspark : error while reading paquet file

Tags: python, pyspark, parquet

I am trying to read a parquet file with pyspark using the command :

```
file = spark.read.parquet("/FileStore/tables/file_name.parquet")
```

The columns in the parquet file have spaces. So I tried to rename the columns using :

```
for c in file.columns:
    file = file.withColumnRenamed(c, c.replace(" ", ""))
```

When I look into the column names and the schema, my columns don't have spaces. However, when I try to display the Dataframe I get the error :

```
AnalysisException: Attribute name "Col Name" contains invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t=". Please use alias to rename it.;
```

Any idea how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Are you sure your columns don't have spaces? Maybe one column have two spaces and you are leaving it with just one space. I would use a dictionary with predefined new names to renamed the columns instead of using replace. 

Also, check if your column is not fill with Na values in all your examples.

Answer (score 1):

How did the parquet file got created . if possible check the mapping of column has space in it or not .

if its not possible try by telling data frame reader api your own schema

some thing like this
schema = "col1 string , col2 int"

df = spark.read.format("parquet")
.option("path",ur_path)
.schema(schema)
.load()
print(df.schema.simplestring())

please check if it helps or not